# click the text box on popover after disable other fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a text box with popover i want to click 1st text box after display popover, now i need to disable background color in using black or any colors using , how can i disable it, how to writ and how to  put this code,

**now my structure** 
[image]

**i need like this**
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.popr').popr();
});

$(document).on('click', '#feugait', function () {
     alert('Feugait');
});
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').on("click",function(){
       $("#messageTextBox").val($(this).find("div").text());
     });
});


(function($) {

     $.fn.popr = function(options) {

          var set = $.extend( {

               'speed'        : 200,
               'mode'         : 'bottom'

          }, options);

          return this.each(function() {

               var popr_cont = '.popr_container_' + set.mode;
               var popr_show = true;

               $(this).click(function(event)
               {
                    $('.popr_container_top').remove();
                    $('.popr_container_bottom').remove();

                    if (popr_show)
                    {
                         event.stopPropagation();
                         popr_show = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         popr_show = true;
                    }

                    var d_m = set.mode;
                    if ($(this).attr('data-mode'))
                    {
                         d_m = $(this).attr('data-mode')
                         popr_cont = '.popr_container_' + d_m;
                    }

                    var out = '<div class="popr_container_' + d_m + '"><div class="popr_point_' + d_m + '"><div class="popr_content">' + $('div[data-box-id="' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '"]').html() + '</div></div></div>';

                    $(this).append(out);

                    var w_t = $(popr_cont).outerWidth();
                    var w_e = $(this).width();
                    var m_l = (w_e / 2) - (w_t / 2);

                    $(popr_cont).css('margin-left', m_l + 'px');
                    $(this).removeAttr('title alt');

                    if (d_m == 'top')
                    {
                         var w_h = $(popr_cont).outerHeight() + 39;
                         $(popr_cont).css('margin-top', '-' + w_h + 'px');
                    }

                    $(popr_cont).fadeIn(set.speed);
               });

               $('html').click(function()
               {
                    $('.popr_container_top').remove();
                    $('.popr_container_bottom').remove();
                    popr_show = true;
               });
          });
     };

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.popr
{
     cursor: pointer;
}
.popr a
{
     color: #333;
     text-decoration: none;
     border: 0;
}
.popr-box
{
     display: none;
}
.popr_content
{
     background-color: #fff;
     padding: 7px 0;
     margin: 0;width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}
.popr-item
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
     color: #333;    text-align: center;
     font-size: 16px;
     padding: 4px 29px 5px 29px; border-bottom: solid 1px #fbeeee;
}
.popr-item:hover
{
     color: #333;
     background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.popr_container_bottom
{
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     margin-top: 10px;
     box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #f9f9f9;
     z-index: 1000;
}
.popr_container_top
{
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #f9f9f9;
     z-index: 1000;
}
.popr_point_top
{
     position: relative;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}
.popr_point_top, .popr_point_bottom {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
   border-radius:  12px;
}
.popr_point_top:after, .popr_point_top:before
{
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 border: solid transparent;
 top: 100%;
 content: "";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
}
.popr_point_top:after
{
 border-top-color: #fff;
 border-width: 8px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -8px;
}
.popr_point_top:before
{
 border-top-color: #dcdcdc;
 border-width: 9px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -9px;
}
.popr_point_bottom:after, .popr_point_bottom:before
{
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 border: solid transparent;
 bottom: 100%;
 content: "";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
}
.popr_point_bottom:after
{
 border-bottom-color: #fff;
 border-width: 8px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -8px;
}
.popr_point_bottom:before
{
 border-bottom-color: #dcdcdc;
 border-width: 9px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -9px;
}
.popover-title {
  text-align: center; color: red;
}

.custom-popover li {
  border: none!important;
  text-align: center;
}

.custom-popover li:nth-child(2) {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc!important;
}

.custom-popover li:last-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc!important;
}
#title-pop {font-size: 12px; color: #b89981;}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class=" popr form-group" data-id="1">
     <a href="#" data-placement="bottom"  title="Bill Category"><input class="form-control input-sm" id="messageTextBox" type="text" placeholder="Select category">
     </a>
     </div>


<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="Description" type="text" placeholder="Description">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="Date" type="text" placeholder="Date">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="Amount" type="text" placeholder="Amount">
</div>




<!-- loaded popover content -->
<div id="popover-section selectBox">
  <div class="selectBox" class="popr-box" data-box-id="1">
<div id="title-pop" class=" popr-item">Bill category
</div>
<a href="#" title="Menu" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover"><div class="popr-item">Staff Payment
</div></a>
  <a href="#" title="Menu" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover"><div class="popr-item">Food and Beverage

</div></a>
<a href="#" title="Menu" data-toggle="popover"  data-trigger="hover"><div class="popr-item">Car rent
</div></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please check this [link](https://codepen.io/sahil_patel/pen/mwZPvP) If it's working then let me know so I can move to answer

Comment: sir, Thank you  for your answer

Comment: is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes sir  i need like this

Comment: Please,  Upvote to answer Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [link](https://codepen.io/sahil_patel/pen/mwZPvP)

I have made one layer `div` with

HTML

```
<div id="layer" class=""></div>
```

CSS

```
.layer{
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index:99;
}
```

JQuery

```
$("#messageTextBox").on('focus',function(){
  $("#layer").addClass("layer");
});

$("#messageTextBox").on('focusout',function(){
  $("#layer").removeClass("layer");
});
```

Explanation:

We are just adding layer class in the div on `focus` of `#messageTextBox` and remove that on `focusout`. The rest of work is done by the layer CSS class